# Create target directory when extracting tarball

Tags: directory, tar

Is it possible to create a target directory, similar to `mkdir -p`, where I can define a non-existent target directory within my tar command, and tar will create the directory for me?

I know I can redirect the output to a directory using `tar -C /target/dir`, but this doesn't work if the target directory is non-existent.

Comment: If it isn't possible, you could always create a shell alias.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
mkdir -p /target/dir && tar -C /target/dir
```

Comment: No spoonfeeding, straight and to the point.

Comment: Minor suggested change:
`mkdir -p /target/dir && tar -C $_`

Comment: @MarkMelville describe to us what $_ supposed to de here

Comment: @Suhayb `$_` is a special parameter in Bash that expands to the last argument to the previous command.

Comment: Why assume BASH?

Answer (score 59):

```
tar -xvf bash.html_node.tar.gz --one-top-level
```

From man page of tar command

> `--one-top-level[=DIR]`
>
>   Extract all files into
>   *DIR*
>   , or, if used without argument, into a
>                   subdirectory named by the base name of the archive
>     (minus standard compression suffixes recognizable by
>   `--auto-compress`
>   ).

----- test

### test 1

```
tar zxvf ../aaa.tgz --one-top-level
aaa/
aaa/222
aaa/111

tree aaa
aaa/
├── 111
└── 222
```

// if tgz name same as root_dir of archive, no other effect

### test 2

```
mv ../aaa.tgz ../bbb.tgz

tar zxvf ../bbb.tgz --one-top-level
aaa/
aaa/222
aaa/111

tree bbb
bbb
└── aaa
    ├── 111
    └── 222
```

// if tgz name not same as root_dir of archive, create a top-level dir

Comment: Requires GNU tar? Mac default bsd tar does not have this option.

Comment: Yes, this should be mentioned more clearly.

Comment: GNU Tar 1.26 does not have the `--one-top-level` option, it appears.

Comment: `--one-top-level` is available as of [GNU Tar 1.28](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2014-07/msg00011.html).

Comment: if it needs to be unarchived to someother destination then use -C option

tar --use-compress-program=unzstd -xvf recipe-zlib.tar.zst --one-top-level -C destination_path

Answer (score 9):

This made more sense to me: `mkdir -p /create/folder && tar -zxf haroopad-v0.13.0_x64.tar.gz -C /create/testfolder`

`mkdir` makes the folder although I don't quite understand the `-p` switch. `&&` lets you execute a second command. I used typical tar switches but at the end `-C` is used to change directories and extract to that location needed.

reference: [extract-files-contained-in-archive-tar-gz-to-new-directory-named-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007947/extract-files-contained-in-archive-tar-gz-to-new-directory-named-archive)

Comment: The -p switch will not throw an error if the directory already exists.

Comment: @David it will also create any leading non-existing directories, i.e. it'll create  `/create` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure if I quite understood it but `-C` doesn't do anything except creating directory which was already created by mkdir.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the paths to create...
Get the needed paths from the tar file, then create them...

```
for P in \`tar tvf tarfile.tar |tr -s [:space:] |cut -d' ' -f6\`; do  
    C=\`echo "${P: -1}"\`  #get the last character  
    if [ $C = '/' ]; then  
        echo "Found directory: $P"  
        mkdir -p $P  
    fi  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers work - but if the contents inside the tar is within a directory - they won't work the way you want:

So this simple trick worked for me:

```
tar -xvzf v<tarball>.tar.gz && mv ./<INSIDE_FOLDER> ./<NEW_FOLDER>
```