# How to prepend a directory to files placed in a tar archive?

Tags: tar, directory-structure

I want to tar the files `foo` and `bar` into a tar archive `archive.tar`, but I want them to appear, within the archive, as being within a directory, `bazdir`. Thus when I untar someplace I want `bazdir` to be created and `foo` and `bar` to be created within it.

How can I do that?

This would be the opposite of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939982/how-do-i-tar-a-directory-of-files-and-folders-without-including-the-directory-it

or
[create flat tar archive: ignoring all parents when adding folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216688/create-flat-tar-archive-ignoring-all-parents-when-adding-folders)

Comment: What about [Create target directory when extracting tarball](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25311/create-target-directory-when-extracting-tarball)? Oh and: [How to create a common base folder with tar and how to rename folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598237/how-to-create-a-common-base-folder-with-tar-and-how-to-rename-folders)

Comment: @Tigger: The first of them requires the decompressing user to, well, know stuff. I'd rather they just `tar xf archive.tar`'ed.

Comment: @Tigger: And the second question has an answer that covers my case, but I didn't notice it (and it's not on this site.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `--transform` option. For example:

```
touch foo bar
tar cf archive.tar foo bar --transform 's,^,bazdir/,'
tar tvf archive.tar 
-rw-r--r-- tigger/tigger     0 2017-10-11 19:32 bazdir/foo
-rw-r--r-- tigger/tigger     0 2017-10-11 19:32 bazdir/bar
```

For more details and more complex options see [How to create a common base folder with tar and how to rename folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598237/how-to-create-a-common-base-folder-with-tar-and-how-to-rename-folders) - on the sister site, ask ubuntu.

Comment: Note that --transform doesn't work with macOS tar.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are on macOS, then use option `-s` instead of `--transform`.

> -s pattern
>
> Modify file or archive member names according to pattern.  The pattern has the format /old/new/[ghHprRsS] where old is a basic
> regular expression, new is the replacement string of the matched part, and the optional trailing letters modify how the replacement
> is handled.  If old is not matched, the pattern is skipped.  Within new, ~ is substituted with the match ...
>
> The optional trailing p specifies that after a successful substitution the original path name and the new path name should be
> printed to standard error.

With above information we can define option `-s` as show below:

```bash
$ tar -c -a -v -s "|.*|prefix/~|p" -f ../out.tar.gz 1.txt 2.txt N.txt

1.txt >> prefix/1.txt
a prefix/1.txt
2.txt >> prefix/2.txt
a prefix/2.txt
```

where

- `|` - is a pattern parts separator instead of default one "/".
- `.*` - is a regex to define "old" part of the pattern (matches everything).
- `prefix/~` - is the expression to prepend to "old" part (defined as "~")
- `p` - is a pattern option to print original and new name of the file to be archived.

Real world example - archiving all files from git repository including submodules:

```bash
$ git ls-files --recurse-submodules | tar -c -a -v --files-from - -s "|.*|1.0.2/~|" --file "dist_1.0.2.tar.gz"

a 1.0.2/.gitignore
a 1.0.2/.gitmodules
a 1.0.2/.prettierignore
a 1.0.2/.prettierrc
a 1.0.2/.vscode/settings.json
a 1.0.2/Gulpfile.mjs
a 1.0.2/Ports.mjs
a 1.0.2/Readme.md
a 1.0.2/Version.cjs
a 1.0.2/app.mjs
a 1.0.2/app.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/jest-fastify-env.mjs
a 1.0.2/jest.babel.config.cjs
a 1.0.2/jest.config.mjs
a 1.0.2/jest.setup.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/conf/Stack.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/.gitignore
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/AWSS3Client.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/Api.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/Api.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/AppConfig.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/DBApi.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/DBClient.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/DBExporter.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/DynamoDBClient.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/DynamoDBConnection.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/RDS.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/RDSClient.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/SecuredApi.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/SecuredApi.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/SecuredApiErrorIds.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/SharedEnv.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/conf/AppEnv.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/CognitoTokenDownloader.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/CognitoTokenDownloader.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/HTTPAuthHelper.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/HTTPAuthHelper.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/Preprocessor.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/Preprocessor.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/TokenVerifier.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/TokenVerifier.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/TokenVerifierErrorIds.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/TypeChecking.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/helpers/TypeChecking.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/testability/TokenFixture.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/types/CustomDateFormatter.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/types/CustomDateFormatter.test.mjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/types/EnvName.cjs
a 1.0.2/lib/shared/types/GenericError.cjs
a 1.0.2/package.json
a 1.0.2/scripts/shared/.gitignore
a 1.0.2/scripts/shared/Prompt.cjs
a 1.0.2/scripts/shared/VersionTool.mjs
a 1.0.2/server.mjs
a 1.0.2/yarn.lock
```

If you double click on "dist_1.0.2.tar.gz" in Finder.app on macOS, then you will see the folder with name "1.0.2" with all archived files inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `bazdir` does not already exist in the current directory, the most straight-forward method that comes to mind is:

```
$ ln -s . bazdir
$ tar cvf myfile.tar bazdir/{foo,bar}
a bazdir/foo
a bazdir/bar
```

Once the `.tar` file is created, we remove the `bazdir` symlink:

```
$ rm bazdir
```

The `.tar` file now contains the directory prefix `bazdir/`:

```
$ tar tvf myfile.tar 
-rw-------  0 jim    wheel       0 Dec 11 13:41 bazdir/foo
-rw-------  0 jim    wheel       0 Dec 11 13:41 bazdir/bar
```

And when we extract the tar file, `bazdir` gets created as a true directory:

```
$ tar xvf myfile.tar 
x bazdir/foo
x bazdir/bar
$ find .
.
./myfile.tar
./foo
./bazdir
./bazdir/bar
./bazdir/foo
./bar
$ file bazdir
bazdir: directory
```

If you prefer not to touch the source directory (or indeed if it's read-only), then place the symlink elsewhere:

```
$ ln -s $(pwd) /tmp/bazdir
$ tar cvf /tmp/myfile.tar -C /tmp bazdir/{foo,bar}
a bazdir/foo
a bazdir/bar
$ rm /tmp/bazdir
$ tar tvf /tmp/myfile.tar 
-rw-------  0 jim    wheel       0 Dec 11 13:41 bazdir/foo
-rw-------  0 jim    wheel       0 Dec 11 13:41 bazdir/bar
```

Comment: Well, +1, but: 1. I needed this 5 years ago and 2. It's a legitimate hack, but I'd rather avoid having to touch the source directory. I suppose you could adapt your approach to use a link from `/tmp` though.

Comment: @einpoklum Re: 1. Bear in mind that one of the purposes of this site is to retain useful answers so that future readers can benefit as well. Re: 2. Good suggestion, I'll include it.

Comment: And IMO, it's not so much a hack as a demonstration of what symlinks are for.  Hard links are so that one can refer to a given file by a different name.  Symlinks are so that one can refer to a given **directory** by a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but clear way is to `rsync` files to some temporary directory and then `tar` them.

`--transform` is a nice feature in many cases, but it gives slightly different archive structure, that may broke unpacking side, when that side is out of our control.